# PHP cURL multiple calls based on id's from database

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to automate 150 cURLS request based on different id's. Every cURL generates an output in JSON. I've these id's in a mysql database.

I think there are the following steps:

1.) get id's from database

2.) construct, load en save output for every cURL based on the id. (www.domain.com//string)

3.) repeat step 2 for each id.

I don't have much experience in this field so my question is where to begin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, that's right flow. let me give you some code that I think will work. Ok, first, we assume we have class DB (I usually use [`meekrodb`](http://meekro.com/docs.php));

```
$dataId = DB::queryOneColumn('id', "SELECT * FROM your_table_data ORDER by some_column LIMIT 150");
DB::startTransaction();
foreach($dataId as $id){
    $response = requestWithCurl($id);
    DB::insert('your_table', array('json_column' => $response));
}
DB::commit();
```

Below is the function to execute cUrl, please see [php curl example](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.examples.php)

```
function requestWithCurl($id){
    # initiate curl
    # define host/url
    # execute curl with data that contain $id
    # return curl response, we assume that response already in json formatted
}
```

Hope this works. :))